# Client Side Events

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm new at JS (and Stack Exchange) but would love to learn more about the lifecycle of my forms, specifically the multipage activity.

I've checked out this page https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/62/data-integration/clientside-events and have been able to get somewhere with the following code:

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/l7xGCnCNMEOaAr1owUlDng"></script>

<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "17" },
          { success: function() { ExoJQuery(function() {
                  ExoJQuery(document)
                 .on('afterNavigate.cognito', function(e, data) {
                ga('send', 'event', 'F1 next', 'Navigate', 'F1 next',{transport: 'beacon'});
              });
      }); } });
  </script>

</div>
```

My two questions are:

1. How can I learn more about which page is being clicked instead of all of the pages in general?
2. Can I both track beforeSubmit.cognito and beforeNavigate.cognito?

Answer (score 0):

**1: How can I learn more about which page is being clicked instead of all of the pages in general?**

You can get more information about the destination page and the source page by using the destinationPage and sourcePage properties off of the data payload. So if I wanted to print the destination page number to the console, I could call use this:

```
<div class="cognito"><script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/l7xGCnCNMEOaAr1owUlDng"></script><script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "17" },
          { success: function() { ExoJQuery(function() {
                  ExoJQuery(document)
                 .on('beforeNavigate.cognito', function(e, data) {
                  console.log(data.destinationPage.number);
              });
      }); } });   </script></div>
```

In the client-side events documentation that you linked, it shows three properties off the pages: the page number, title, and name.

**2: Can I both track beforeSubmit.cognito and beforeNavigate.cognito?**

Yes. Just add a new *ExoJQuery(document).on* function after the first one.

```
<div class="cognito"><script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/l7xGCnCNMEOaAr1owUlDng"></script><script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "17" },
          { 
              success: function() 
              { 
                  ExoJQuery(function() 
                  {
                        ExoJQuery(document).on('beforeNavigate.cognito', function(e, data) 
                        {
                             console.log(data.destinationPage.number);
                        });
                        ExoJQuery(document).on('afterNavigate.cognito', function(e, data) 
                        {
                             console.log(data.sourcePage.number);
                        });
                   });
               } 
           });
  </script></div>
```

The formatting is irrelevant, I just think this is easier to read :)

[*Note: I'm a software developer at Cognito Forms*]